# Keeping database synced in all of my computers

Tags: mysql, synchronization

I have 1 PC (windows 8.1) and 1 Macbook pro. I am working on a PHP project with mysql database backend but is switching between these 2 computers. The PC has WAMP installed and the macbook pro has MAMP installed. Both have different versions of Apache, PHP and MySQL but that doesn't matter - what matters is the MySQL version. PC has MySQL 5.5.24 and mac has 5.5.33.

I successfully have the PHP files synced via dropbox and symbolic links so any update I do on any computer will reflect and be saved on the other. The problem is the database, I tried syncing the binary data folder (data/) with each other, the source data is the one from Macbook. Now when it syncs to the PC, upon starting mysql I got a few errors:

```
140116  5:47:35 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140116  5:47:35 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140116  5:47:35 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
140116  5:47:35 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140116  5:47:35 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140116  5:47:35 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140116  5:47:36 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140116  5:47:36  InnoDB: Operating system error number 87 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: File name .\ib_logfile0
InnoDB: File operation call: 'aio read'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Anyone knows how to resolve this or is there a better way to have it synced?
DATABASE is InnoDB type

Comment: Can you use a backup and restore method?

Comment: What do you mean? I want to it to be synced and not backup/restore a dump everytime I do a work on a computer then move to the laptop to update the database. I wanted it automated

Comment: I'm only suggesting that as one possible method. If that doesn't work for your needs then don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

Three options:

1) Open you PC to outside connections and use it from both locations

2) You get a small hosted server and host your MySQL database there.

3) Create a MySQL dump from the last used database and restore it on the other one. (Can take time depending on how big is your data)

Comment: For now thats what I'm going to do and have a remote MySQL server to host the DB. However I wanted this problem solved just for the sake of having it solved. I had set the innodb_file_per_table to ON so that the data resides outside ibdata and I could sync them, but still database won't work correctly as it should.

Comment: I would check on the permissions side, from your mac terminal can you do "ls -lthra" in the folder where your ibdata is ?